# Permission needed to use ScriptDb in new project

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to use `ScriptDb` in a new project which is run as a GAS in the web-site. As soon as the row `var stored = db.save(ob);` is added, even as commented!, to the code the GAS does not work anymore. It try's to load the GAS but instead on the screen appears "You need permission to do this" <-- free translation from my language! :-) In the old project the DB works fine.

Actually I noticed that for Example `var results = db.query({employee_id: 1});` causes the same. So it seems that no DB related is allowed...

I use this same code in both projects:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var ob = {type: "employee",
            employee_id: 1,
            department_id: 52};
var stored = db.save(ob);
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you add a new service that needs authorization, you will have to explicitly authorize the script from the Script Editor.

Open the script editor, run any function, you will be prompted for authorization. Complete the authorization process.

Comment: Thank you Srik, your answer was perfect!